# Conditional random allocation in Python

Tags: python, random

I need to conditionally randomly allocate users to groups. The table governing the process is as follows:

```
   A  B  C
0  9  1  1
1  1  7  8
2  0  2  1
```

According to the above matrix, there's a total of 11 users from area 0, 16 from area 1, and 3 from area 2.

Furthermore, of the 11 users from area 0, 9 should be allocated to group A, 1 each should be allocated to B and C. The process is analogous for the rest of the groups.

I have some code in Python:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [9,1,0], "B": [1,7,2], "C": [1,8,1]})
random.sample(range(1,df.sum(axis=1)[0] + 1),df.sum(axis=1)[0])
```

The last line creates a random vector of integers e.g. `[1, 4, 10, 2, 5, 11, 9, 3, 8, 7, 6]`. I can allocate indices from 1 to 9 to group A, 
the index with 10 to group B, the index with 11 to group C. In other words, user 3 goes to group B, user 6 goes to group C, and all the rest go to group A.

The desired output would be `[A,A,B,A,A,C,A,A,A,A,A]`, or even better, a pandas dataframe like:

```
1 A
2 A 
3 B
4 A
5 A
6 C
...
```

How can I automate the process I described in words above? (the actual allocation matrix is 10 x 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.repeat` to get an array with the right number of users:

```
In [38]: [np.repeat(df.columns, row) for row in df.values]
Out[38]: 
[Index(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object'),
 Index(['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C',
        'C', 'C'],
       dtype='object'),
 Index(['B', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object')]
```

And then permute them:

```
In [39]: [np.random.permutation(np.repeat(df.columns, row)) for row in df.values]
Out[39]: 
[array(['C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], dtype=object),
 array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C',
        'C', 'B', 'B'], dtype=object),
 array(['B', 'C', 'B'], dtype=object)]
```

and then you could call pd.Series on each array if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks! This was very well explained.